# jQuery total amount of elements in an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, indexing

Seems like a simple thing but I cant find anything on it!

```
var cookie = [1,2,3],
    total  = cookie.magicMethodThatICantFindThatTotalsTheElements();

total = 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) specifies the number of elements in array:

```
var total = cookie.length;
```